# initializing the private member of a struct

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

Right now i have

```
Private:
Struct PageManagerData
{
   char name[20];
   IPage* storePagePtr;
}
```

I would like to initialize name to something like `'\0'` and storePagePtr to `NULL` but right now i cannot access these values in constructor in order to initialize them. How do I do it?

Comment: That declares a nested type but not an instance.

Answer (score 9):

Your code doesn't look like valid C++

```
struct PageManagerData
{
   PageManagerData() : name { 0 }, storePagePtr(nullptr) { }
private:
   char name[20];
   IPage* storePagePtr;
};
```

That's still not typical C++:

```
struct PageManagerData
{
private:
   std::string name;
   std::unique_ptr<IPage> storePage;
};
```

This avoids an enormous host of potential memory management/initialization/buffer overrun errors. Specifically, it leverages the [Rule Of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/): you can do without implementing special members

- (move) constructors
- (move) assignment
- destructor

and enjoy robust object value semantics, without leaks and UB.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a constructor of the structure that does the initialization you mention.